# GPU Accelerated data plotting in Python

Tags: python, plot, cuda

I have a general question regarding using CUDA acceleration in Python. Is it possible to accelerate the plotting of data generated by matplotlib command using CUDA ? Any weblinks/documents/examples are much appreciated.

Comment: @talonmies I think your *one word answer* is a good, valid and trusted answer. Why close this question if it is not a duplicate? One word answer is always the best. (Disclaimer: I read SO's resume)

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: Because the question is really asking for offsite resources (links to examples, documentation etc) which are specifically off-topic for [SO]

Comment: @talonmies but your *one word answer* is an good answer to *Is it possible to accelerate the plotting of data generated by matplotlib command using CUDA ?*

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: Any question which can be answered in one word doesn't belong on [SO] anyway.

Comment: @talonmies, although the one word answer of "No" may have been strictly true, it seems more kindly to answer the intent of the question, which was if the GPU could harnessed in python plotting.  Since a lot of people equate GPU with CUDA, I think it's helpful to the community to leave the question the way it is, and apparently the asker found my answer below helpful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe not with CUDA, but if you are interested in harnessing the power of your GPU, check out [Vispy](http://vispy.org/).  From the Vispy page:

"Vispy leverages the computational power of modern Graphics Processing Units (GPUs) through the OpenGL library to display very large datasets".

And it does that very nicely: [image: screengrab]:
http://screencast.com/t/e16BG1iccdw